# Laravel Quiz Storing The correct answers

Tags: php, laravel

I am **very new** to the Laravel, so I have a project for making a quiz. Currently I achieved to store my questions with radio-answers in the database, but I do not know how to:

> 1) Display all the questions with answers on web page.
>
> 2) Store the points for the user on each correct answer.

***UPDATE:*** Thanks to *ettdro* I have solved my 1st problem. Only my 2nd left.

I would appreciate any help.
My *Answer.php* Model is empty for now. My *Question.php* Model:

```
class Question extends Model
{
  // connect the models by adding a relationship to the Question model
  public function answers()
  {
      return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
  }
}
```

My *up* function in *Migration* for *Questions* is:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('text');
            $table->integer('points')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

My *up* function in *Migration* for *Answers* is:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('answers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            // since answer is connected to the question
            $table->integer('question_id');
            $table->string('text');
            $table->boolean('correct_one');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

My *QuestionAnswerSeeder.php* is:

```
// for filling the tables
class QuestionAnswerSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    // truncating the tables and then store each question and its answers.
    public function run()
    {
      Question::truncate();
      Answer::truncate();
      $questionAndAnswers = $this->getData();

      $questionAndAnswers->each(function ($question) {
          $createdQuestion = Question::create([
              'text' => $question['question'],
              'points' => $question['points'],
          ]);

          collect($question['answers'])->each(function ($answer) use ($createdQuestion) {
              Answer::create([
                  'question_id' => $createdQuestion->id,
                  'text' => $answer['text'],
                  'correct_one' => $answer['correct_one'],
              ]);
          });
      });
    }

    // for the actual data, I use a separate getData method to keep it cleaner
    // in this method, I return a big collection with all the questions and answers
    private function getData()
    {
        return collect([
            [
                'question' => 'When did the World War 2 end?',
                'points' => '1',
                'answers' => [
                    ['text' => '1939', 'correct_one' => false],
                    ['text' => '1941', 'correct_one' => false],
                    ['text' => '1945', 'correct_one' => true],
                ],
            ],
            [
                'question' => 'Who discovered America?',
                'points' => '1',
                'answers' => [
                    ['text' => 'Adolf Hitler', 'correct_one' => false],
                    ['text' => 'Napoleon Bonaparte', 'correct_one' => false],
                    ['text' => 'Christopher Columbus', 'correct_one' => true],
                ],
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Do you have a controller where you pass the data to your view? If so, you should only pass something like: ```Question::all()```, this will pass a collection of questions that are stored in your Questions table in your database.
2. Can you show me your code that is used in your controller?

Comment: @enttdro Thank you for the feedback, I have both QuestionController and AnswerController and they both are empty for now.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a `QuestionController.php` that has this content:

```
/**
  * In this function, you need to get all the data you want to pass to your view
  *  and send it to the compact function in the return statement.
  */
public function index() {
    // This will return a collection of questions including their answers.
    $questionsCollection = Question::all();
    return view('myquestionsview', compact('questionsCollection'));
}
```

Next, because you returned `myquestionsview` in the index function, you will need a file named: `myquestionsview.blade.php` in the `views` folder.

To display the informations of your questions, in your `myquestionsview.blade.php` you should have something like

```
@foreach ($questions as $question)
    {{ $question->text }}
    // Now, we want to display each answers of the question.
    @foreach ($question->answers as $answer)
        {{ $answer->text }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

This is basically what you want to do for your first question.

Comment: You do not have anything that refers to ```App\Http\Controllers\Question``` in your files. Are you trying to import your model ```Question.php``` instead? If so, try importing it like this: ```use App\Models\Question``` or ```App\Question``` depending on where is your Question.php file. Please check out this link to learn more on controllers and how to use them: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers. Laravel Docs is well built and really awesome, it makes solving laravel problems way easier :)

Comment: I have solved my problem, thank you, however in QuestionController.php it supposed to be Question::all(); instead of Question::with('answers')->all();

Comment: Oh my bad, but you should definitely check the ```with()``` method in the docs, could be helpful :)